# How to get sock marks off legs quickly

Tags: clothing, personal-care

I have to wear boots with socks all day for work and then when I want to go out at night and wear a skirt with bare legs, I have lines from my socks around my ankles.  Has anyone found a way of making them fade faster?

Comment: <comments removed> Reminder: If you have an answer to this question, please post it below. Comments do not have the feature to properly vet and vote on your information. Answers saying "I don't know, but maybe..." only make that situation worse, so answers are not allowed in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No hacky answer here I'm afraid - I know from experience (having the same trouble) that there isn't a way of removing those marks other than waiting for the body to do it naturally - depending how old you are, that can take a couple or three hours or overnight. What you could do, though, is buy different socks with a longer, slouchy top to allow for expansion, so when your legs swell as the day goes on, no marks from tight socks are showing. Alternatively, wear light or medium support tights beneath the trousers and put the socks on over the top on days when you know you'll be wanting to wear a dress or skirt later. Check, though, that the socks you're wearing aren't simply really tight at the top anyway - some are tighter than others.

I did resort to cutting through the top band with a pair of scissors on tighter pairs, angling the cut towards the foot of the sock - but the sock then tends to disappear downwards, bunching up under your foot as the day goes on if you're wearing boots, not always, but often.

Comment: Your loose socks idea reminded me of the "sock suspenders" that Sean Connery wore in one of the James Bond movies. I couldn't find a picture of that, but here's a picture of sock suspenders: http://cdn.styleforum.net/8/8e/350x700px-LL-8e3f3ee9_Stayups2012-05-10006.jpeg

Comment: How very unattracive they are! And they'd leave marks too, just higher up, under the knee...

Comment: They're called garters. Garter belt for women's gear.

Comment: @Stan - not in the UK they're not, garter refers to a quite different bit of kit, sometimes worn by women for entertainment purposes....originally intended to hold up stockings but these days worn singly, essentially a highly decorative covered stretch of elastic...

Comment: @Stan - and suspender belt (or if you're from the North, sussie belt) not garter belt, not that it matters, just as a point of interest. More important you don't describe sock suspenders as garters, you'd get some very funny looks in the UK!

Comment: Well THAT explains it. : ) @Bamboo thanks, I enjoy your posts and find them informative and beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

I've not actually tested this, but I was told by a relative that you can make these sock marks disappear quicker by rubbing moisturiser on it - the same apparently works for when you get a pillow crease on your face when you wake up in the morning (although this is again untested by me - I have enough permanent creases that one temporary one doesn't matter...!)

Answer (score 0):

Have a hot bath and rub the area with your hands/sponge. The heat and friction will get circulation going and the imprints will be less.

Answer (score 0):

Try socks made for diabetic patients.

I got a pair and I love them because they are comfortable, have no rubber elastic or other constricting stretchy stuff in them. I found them at local drug stores, in the pharmacy section of super markets, and super store chains. They must be available online, too. They are inexpensive enough to try a pair.

They come in different colours and kinds from thick sports socks, socklets, and men's dress calf-length. None need garters to stay up.

They won't leave marks as the normal ones do. I think you'll be satisfied.

Ideally, you could get socks that were sized for your feet and your calf size separately. Unfortunately mass produced sock size templates do not accommodate all the different variations of human bodies.