# Preventing socks from leaving marks on skin

Tags: clothing, personal-care, comfort

I have a pair of socks that leave marks on the skin. Since I can't throw them away, I need a solution that helps me wear these socks without leaving any mark and feel comfortable as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7554/how-to-get-sock-marks-off-legs-quickly

Comment: Is it just the top, elasticated part of the sock that's leaving a mark?

Comment: @James Webster Yes. Also elasticated part can't be removed as it will make socks slip down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - Is it just the top, elasticated part of the sock that's leaving a mark?
> - Yes.

Fold the elastic down once so that the sock itself provides a small cushion between the elastic and your skin.

[image]
[image]

```
             Before                            After
```

You could also pull the sock down slightly on to a slimmer part of your leg nearer the ankle.

Answer (score 1):

Although, for a more left-field answer...

If the elastic is still too tight for the rolling method described by James, you could always break the elastic and find an alternative way to hold your socks up.

[Staysput Irish Dancing Sock Glue](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Staysput-Irish-Dancing-Sock-Glue/dp/B00JR6NJO2)

Sock Glue exists, and is intended mainly to hold up long (overknee) socks.  It's surprisingly widely used - from professional dancers to Japanese girls looking to maintain the ["absolute territory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettai_ry%C5%8Diki) effect.

It attests to being long-lasting, and apparently leaves no marks when washed off.